# Wrong time after wake up from suspend

Tags: system, suspend, time

every time my system wakes up from suspend it shows the wrong time, even though it is set to get the network time.
What could be the issue?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Thought it was Wednesday for a moment when it was actually Thusrday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [searched Github for related issues](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+user%3Aelementary+suspend+time) and it appears to be a known bug:

https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/306

Comment: Ok sad to hear that. So the best we can do is waiting for a bugfix. Might come with eOS 6.